# Webform (*) instead of required word

Tags: 7, webforms

I have a situation I want to put (*) instead of "required" word inside the place holder of a webform field is it possible from webform admin.

Comment: Which version of webform module you are using ?

Comment: version 7.x-3.19

Answer (score 0):

You can add this (*) in field label with field name or can use with style also.

Answer (score 0):

You can always write a [hook_preprocees_HOOK](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7) in your theme's template.php, in this case it would be

```
<?php
function THEME_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
   if ($element['#field_name'] == 'field_YOURFIELD' && $element['#bundle'] == 'webform' && $element['#view_mode'] == 'full') {
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'field__field_WEBFORM_MY_TPL';
    $variables['ANOTHER VARIABLE_TO_OUTPUT'] = 'preprocessed';
  }
}
```

where you can manipulate the vars for this field, or even set your own template by copying the field tpl to your needs

Comment: So nice, you mean to say that there is no other option instead of using preprocess.

Comment: Hmm, no i don't say it's the only option.It is just the best option if you like to have everything controlled in your own code in a Drupal standards way.